# Replacement for Item Level Permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, designer-workflow, splistitem, splist

I have a SharePoint calender list and where i have given item level permissions for each event through designer workflow using the impersonation step. But now on the production site the number of events in the list have reached 18000 and the item level permissions are making my custom  control very slow.

I have found that a stored procedure called **"proc_GetUniqueScopesInList"** takes about 3000 ms to execute.

So is there a way where i can remove the item level permissions but still maintain the security level?

Comment: Why not just archive old items, 18000 items in a calendar likely means a lot of stuff from years ago that is no longer relevant.

Comment: Is there a direct way to archive, or will i have to create another list of same kind?

Comment: export to excel/access, then delete the old items. store the file under lock somewhere if the data is still sensitive. It really depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

We are in a similar situation.

We recognized that in some case our permissions are unqiue but allways the same :) (unique permissions in some flow was always setting the same 2 AD groups). This is helpful as we can move these items down into a folder that has the unique permissions without having to assign it to each item individually, reducing the amount of unique scopes. We will also be splitting the "active" items from the old ones. You can look into Record Management in SharePoint, as that's kind of its purpose.

If you really need the unique permissions on a lot of items in the same list, you can try this: https://www.martinhatch.com/2011/10/scaling-to-10000-unique-permissions_04.html. It's helpful if your users that get the unique permissions already have read access on the container. Then you avoid adding each of them again with "Limited Access" up to the SPWeb scope.

Comment: But when you use SharePoint designer workflow to add item level permissions i.e.(impersonation step) there is no additional "Limited Access" entry

Comment: Really ? Did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the item level permission then you cannot get the same security level. Once you removed the item level then you move list level permissions. user can get the view / edit / delete at list level.

To get this done, you may think about 3rd party solutions.

How much total time Page taking to load. 3000 MS mean 3 sec that's not bad in my opinion, if total time is under 5 seconds

Comment: Sometimes it even takes about 5-7 secs

Comment: 7 sec is bad. You have to re think your strategy. other ways to handle the item level permission, may 3rd party tool an option